# Is it possible to have a runtime of O(n) with just one while loop?

Tags: python, time-complexity, runtime, big-o

If there are no other loops inside of that while loop, is it possible to have O(n^2) runtime?

Comment: Yes, if you call a function that has O(n) complexity inside the loop, or the loop can go to n^2. One loop does not means O(n) complexity

Comment: The number of loops or nested loops does not determine the complexity. You can have any complexity including O(1) with any number of nested loops.

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question. And what does it have to do with Python?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, sure! Your runtime will be determined by how long it takes to meet your termination condition on the loop. If your program makes a small amount of progress on each iteration, it might well take worse than linear time. For example, consider the following bubble sort implementation:

```
to_sort = [1,5,2,3,7,6,4]

sorted = True
i = 0

while not sorted or i < len(to_sort):
    if i == len(to_sort):
        sorted = True
        i = 0
    if i < len(to_sort) - 1 and to_sort[i] > to_sort[i + 1]:
        to_sort[i], to_sort[i + 1] = to_sort[i + 1], to_sort[i]
        sorted = False
    i += 1

print(to_sort)
```

You'll notice that I'm mistreating my `i` variable a little bit. That's because bubble sort is usually written as nested loops. But it's often possible to rewrite nested loops as one, more complicated, less readable loop, as I did here.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(n * n):
    foo(i)
```

```
for i in range(2 ** n):
    <look at bits of i>
```

Loops with runtime O(n^2) and O(2^n).  You need to be a **lot** more specific about your question.

Comment: To be precise, the second complexity would be O(log n * 2^n) if you're looking at all the bits of `i`. And the first complexity is O(n^2*f(n)) where f is the complexity of foo.

Comment: @MoB.  Yeah, you're right.   I was being a bit imprecise.  But the point's the same.  The question wasn't specific enough.